# Logic App - Convert "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" to Milliseconds since Epoch

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps

I GET below JSON data from source with date in "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" format, and I want to convert the it to the Milliseconds to Epoch before sending it to destination, can someone help how to do it in Logic App?

Source data:

```
{
   "result":[
      {
         "number":"123",
         "name":"ABC",
         "created":"2018-09-19 09:03:03"
      }
   ]
}
```

Desired data:

```
{
   "result":[
      {
         "number":"123",
         "name":"ABC",
         "created":"1537304583000"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure logic app only has [the ticks method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#ticks) that can convert the timestamp to an ticks number.

You can use [the sub method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#sub) to convert the value after ticks conversion to an `Epoch` by subtraction.

[image]

Expression:

```
sub(ticks('2018-09-19 09:03:03'),636727908525417000)
```

`636727908525417000` is the difference between `ticks('2018-09-19 09:03:03')` and the `1537304583000` you gave.

You can refer to this article:

https://devkimchi.com/2018/11/04/converting-tick-or-epoch-to-timestamp-in-logic-app/

Answer (score 1):

Logic Apps expression to get current time in Epoch format:

```
div(sub(ticks(utcNow()),621355968000000000),10000000) //Hardcoded Epoch provided

div(sub(ticks(utcNow()),ticks("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z")),10000000)
```

**Explanation:**

1. [`utcNow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#utcNow) gets datetime, by default in format of ["o" (yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffK)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#utcNow).

   - `utcNow()` can be replace with [`ticks("myTimestamp")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#ticks) or [`parseDateTime("myTimestamp")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#parseDateTime) or `trigger().startTime`
2. [`ticks()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#ticks)/`ticks(utcNow())` converts datetime to [100-nanosecond intervals since `January 1, 0001 12:00:00`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#ticks), aka "ticks".
3. Hardcoded value: `621355968000000000` - equal to ticks value of `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`, aka start of Unix Epoch. `ticks("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z")` should also work.
4. [`sub()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#sub)/`sub(ticks(utcNow()),621355968000000000)` subtracts number of ticks of your datetime from hardcoded ticks value of start of Unix Epoch.
5. [`div()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#div)/`div(sub(ticks(utcNow()),621355968000000000),10000000)` by dividing ticks by 10,000,000 you convert the ticks from 100-nanoseconds into milliseconds.